# Unable to read TimeZoneInfo from MongoDB document

Tags: c#, mongodb, timezone, mongodb-query

I have a C# object which contains a `TimeZoneInfo` property. I am able to save it to MongoDB. But When I am retrieving it back, It is coming as empty. All other properties are mapped properly.

My `DTO` structure looks like this below; there are other things also but I have mentioned only few properties:

```
public class TerminalDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public GeographyDto Geography { get; set; }
    public GeoCoordinateDto GeoCoordinate { get; set; }
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get; set; }
}
```

My mongo document is being stored as :

```
{
    "_id": "5bc4601d5d46855e6c8a337b",
    "Code": "AK",
    "Geography": {
        "City": "Akron",
        "State": {
            "Name": "OHIO",
            "Code": "OH"
        }
    },
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "Latitude": "40.97665",
        "Longitude": "-81.464607"
    },
    "TimeZone": {
        "_id": "Eastern"
    }
}
```

When I am reading it back, my `DTO` properties are filled except the `TimeZone info`.

```
{
    "_id": "5bc4601d5d46855e6c8a337b",
    "Code": "AK",
    "Geography": {
        "City": "Akron",
        "State": {
            "Name": "OHIO",
            "Code": "OH"
        }
    },
    "GeoCoordinate": {
        "Latitude": "40.97665",
        "Longitude": "-81.464607"
    },
    "TimeZone": {} // Empty Here
}
```

My Terminal Repository is some what like this.

```
public class TerminalRepository
{
    public TerminalRepository(IMongoConnectionFactory mongoConnectionFactory)
    {
        this.collection = mongoConnectionFactory.GetCollection<TerminalDto>();
    }

    private readonly IMongoCollection<TerminalDto> collection;

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TerminalDto>> GetTerminals(int scenarioId)
    {
        var filter = Builders<TerminalDto>.Filter.Eq(t => t.ScenarioId, scenarioId);
        var dtos = (await this.collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToList();
    }
}
```

I tried searching on MongoDB official documentation but could not find any information related to storing `TimeZoneInfo`.

How do I work it out?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: @JohnnyHK TimeZoneInfo is a system defined class in C#. I am referring to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not serialize the `TimeZoneInfo` class into your document, but rather just the `.Id` property.  There are many ways to do this, but one way would be with a "buddy property", such as this:

```
public class TerminalDto
{
    // ... your other properties ...

    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(this.TimeZoneId);
        }

        set
        {
            this.TimeZoneId = value.Id;
        }
    }
}
```